# type for time field in Golang + mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, go, timestamp

I have struct:

```
type TripFeedback struct {
    ID        primitive.ObjectID `json:"_id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    UserID    string             `json:"user_id" bson:"user_id"`
    WaybillID uint64             `json:"waybill_id" bson:"waybill_id"`
    Rating    Rating             `json:"rating" bson:"rating"`
    Comment   string             `json:"comment" bson:"comment"`
    CreatedAt time.Time          `json:"created_at" bson:"created_at"`
}
```

When i create an object it looks like this (look at time):

```
0: {ObjectID("010000000000000000000000") 53566444-4334-11ee-be56-0242ac120002 5 4  2023-08-25 13:44:22.89 +0000 UTC}
1: {ObjectID("020000000000000000000000") 53566444-4334-11ee-be56-0242ac120002 12 4  2023-08-25 13:44:22.89 +0000 UTC}
2: {ObjectID("030000000000000000000000") 53566444-4334-11ee-be56-0242ac120002 51 3  2023-08-25 13:44:22.89 +0000 UTC}
3: {ObjectID("040000000000000000000000") 53566444-4334-11ee-be56-0242ac120002 53 5  2023-08-25 13:44:22.89 +0000 UTC}
4: {ObjectID("050000000000000000000000") 53566444-4334-11ee-be56-0242ac120002 53 5  2023-08-25 13:44:22.89 +0000 UTC}
5: {ObjectID("060000000000000000000000") 53566444-4334-11ee-be56-0242ac120002 54 4  2023-08-25 13:44:22.89 +0000 UTC}
```

But when i get response from mongodb and parse it to same struct it looks like this:

```
0: {ObjectID("010000000000000000000000") 53566444-4334-11ee-be56-0242ac120002 5 4  2023-08-25 13:44:22.8902373 +0000 UTC m=+0.005347601}
1: {ObjectID("020000000000000000000000") 53566444-4334-11ee-be56-0242ac120002 12 4  2023-08-25 13:44:22.8902373 +0000 UTC m=+0.005347601}
2: {ObjectID("030000000000000000000000") 53566444-4334-11ee-be56-0242ac120002 51 3  2023-08-25 13:44:22.8902373 +0000 UTC m=+0.005347601}
3: {ObjectID("040000000000000000000000") 53566444-4334-11ee-be56-0242ac120002 53 5  2023-08-25 13:44:22.8902373 +0000 UTC m=+0.005347601}
4: {ObjectID("050000000000000000000000") 53566444-4334-11ee-be56-0242ac120002 53 5  2023-08-25 13:44:22.8902373 +0000 UTC m=+0.005347601}
5: {ObjectID("060000000000000000000000") 53566444-4334-11ee-be56-0242ac120002 54 4  2023-08-25 13:44:22.8902373 +0000 UTC m=+0.005347601}
```

Why are time fields different? How to deal with it? Shouldn't my `CreatedAt` be `time.Time` type?(cause at least i have to write some tests). Thanks you

Comment: You are probably just printing the timestamp in which case monotonic clock comes into play (read about it in package time!). Nothing to see here. Nothing to do here. Except: Stop just fmt.Print...ing stuff; at least without understanding what fmt does and how each type behaves.

Answer (score 0):

The values are the same, you can ignore the `m=` piece. `TripFeedback.CreatedAt` is of type `time.Time`, it cannot be any other type as Go is a statically-typed language.